# Computing training score using cross_val_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am using `cross_val_score` to compute the mean score for a regressor. Here's a small snippet.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score 

cross_val_score(LinearRegression(), X, y_reg, cv = 5)
```

Using this I get an array of scores. I would like to know how the scores on the validation set (as returned in the array above) differ from those on the training set, to understand whether my model is over-fitting or under-fitting.

Is there a way of doing this with the `cross_val_score` object?

Comment: Pass in your training set and see.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Why would you want that? `cross_val_score(cv=5)` does that for you as it splits your train data 10 times and verifies accuracy scores on 5 test subsets. This method already serves as a way to prevent your model from over-fitting.

Anyway, if you are eager to verify accuracy on your validation data, then you have to fit your LinearRegression first on **X** and **y_reg**.

Comment: Hi E.Z. I thought it would be possible to predict on the training set used in the X-Validation iterator as well to get an understanding of any potential overfitting. Perhaps this is not possible.

Comment: Potential overfitting is easily neglected when using cross_val_score as it trains and predicts on different subsets of X and then validates accuracy. Those test subsets are like X_validation in your case. But fitting with your scenario is rather obsolete. You can read more about the process of over-fitting here: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#overfitting_and_regularization. It relates more to the neural networks section but the meaning is absolutely the same. Thank you.

Comment: @E.Z. do we prevent overfitting always ?

Comment: Cross-validation is a well-established technique - it works consistently.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `cross_validate` instead of `cross_val_score`
according to [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#the-cross-validate-function-and-multiple-metric-evaluation):

> The `cross_validate` function differs from `cross_val_score` in two ways -
>
> - It allows specifying multiple metrics for evaluation.
> - It returns a dict containing **training scores**, fit-times and score-times in addition to the **test score**.